# Problem sending messages from camel xmpp, jid-malformed

Tags: java, apache-camel, xmpp

I'm trying to send a (private) direct message from A@jabber.de to a user B@jabber.de with the camel-xmpp-component. But it always says "jid-malformed".
Used this documentation: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/xmpp-component.html

Using camel 2.24.2 and java 8 but same problem on java 11.
I also tried to set "from" and "to" in the MessageHeaders.
I also looked in the source code of the component and it always building the "from"-JID to something with "chat@..." which is not like all other tutorials using the smack library like here: https://www.baeldung.com/xmpp-smack-chat-client

```java
from("timer:sendMessage?period=5000")
        .setBody(constant("test"))
        .to("xmpp:A@jabber.de:5222/B@jabber.de?user=A&password=xxx");
```

I expected to send a message but it logins in successfully and when sending I get the following error in the log:

```
o.a.c.c.xmpp.XmppLogger        | INBOUND : <message to='A@jabber.de/Camel' from='B@jabber.de@chat:B@jabber.de:A' id='BdCI4-9' type='error'><error type='modify'><jid-malformed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>The destination address is invalid: B@jabber.de@chat:B@jabber.de:A</text></error></message>
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I having similar issues sending messages directly to a user, but can receive messages and send to chat rooms. I would also appreciate any ideas on this. Using Camel 2.24.2 and Openfire 4.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread name is appended to the JID when a private message is created.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blame/master/components/camel-xmpp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xmpp/XmppPrivateChatProducer.java#L98

I'm no expert on XMPP or Smack, but it seems that Openfire (in my case) is not happy about the thread name in the JID. And after removing the thread name I'm able to send private messages.

I have submitted this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14194) to the Camel bug tracker.

Comment: Should be fixed in Camel 2.24.3 and 3.0.0, when they are rleased

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the trailing slashes after "xmpp:".

Comment: I'm sorry, but this did not make any difference. usually the slashes are not needed